# Menu settings missing from all node edit forms

Tags: 7, routes

Apart from what I mention in the title, there are also a couple of other things that give me the impression that they may be related to the same issue:

- **Can’t add link to any menu from
  admin/structure/menu/manage/my-menu/add**. What does happen when I try
  to add a link to any menu is that it ends up in the Navigation menu
  that comes OOTB.
- **Can’t assign any menu to taxonomy menu**. Having `taxonomy_menu`
  enabled, I noticed that when configuring the vocabulary via
  admin/structure/taxonomy/gamma/edit  there is no possiblity to assign
  any menu as taxonomy menu. The only option in the drop-down list is
  `=NONE=`

There is also A list of modules on which I did this series of events: disabled the module, cleared cache, checked if the problem persisted (which it obviously did), and enabled the module again:

Here is the list:

Big Menu
Jump Menu
Mysite configurator (custom)
Mysite (custom)
Store locator (custom)
roleperm_import (custom)
mforms
mforms example
Menu Block
Menu import
Menu translation
Taxonomy menu _ custom paths
Taxonomy menu
Administration views
Backup and Migrate
Taxonomy translation
Menu translation

Needless to say the core *Menu* module is enabled.

Went looking on the internet, found this issue (https://drupal.org/node/358844) on drupal.org but this was drupal6 plus the big problem there was that the everything menu related seemed to be missing. The solution there was that menu permission weren’t right, which I have verified on my site that they are ok.

Answer (score 1):

> "Menu settings missing from all node edit forms"

You need to enable the menus for use on each content type. This can be achieved on pages via Structure->Content type->Basic page, then click on the "Menu settings" vertical tab and toggle which menus should be enabled.

Also, if you're using the revisioning system in core, or any kind of workflow type module (workflow or workbench), unpublished pages in the menu won't show up in your list of menu items in Structure->Menus->Main Menu (for example), as well as the obvious rendered menu on the front end too.

Comment: All content types have at least 'Main menu' enabled as available menus. So this part configuration can't seem to be the cause either.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed tht. Can you try disable menu_translation to see if that has an affect? If it does, it probably needs your menus enabled for the language the content is getting created in.

Comment: Oh but you didn't miss that, your comment was helpful so I checked the thing Menu Settings in the Content Type settings after your comment. Disabling `menu_translation` I did verify already though, unfortunately without any success.

Comment: I can also confirm that the revisioning system is not being used. Neither the workbench module or the workflow module is installed on the site.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a tough one. Are you double sure none of your custom modules aren't doing something crazy to $form['menu'] in a hook_form_alter()?

Comment: I'm very well sure of that yes, since I also cleared cache after I disabled the custom modules one by one.